# How do I execute code that is taken as user input?

Tags: python, input

Is there a way to actually take a ***well formatted*** input and execute it at an appropriate time?

Something like:

```
num = 5
command = input()
# do something with command
```

Now, if i enter `"print(num)"` as input, it should output

```
5
```

Comment: For java, there is beanshell: http://www.beanshell.org/ It allows to interpret Java source code.

Comment: It's all fun and games until someone inputs a program that formats your hard drive or installs a key logger. All while running with privileges.

Comment: The input to `eval` or `exec` has to be not only formatted correctly, it **must** come from a trusted source. `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. Also note that  `eval` / `exec` are _slow_.

Comment: "a well formatted input" is not a sensible presumption in the real world. Treat every input as bad, unless you can show it is good.

Comment: Excellent link,  PM 2Ring. Exactly what I was looking for. It not only answered my question, not only stated the risks, but also gave me ideas to avoid such risks. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest actually works as is:

```
>>> x=1
>>> eval(input())
print(x)
1
```

Another method you can have a look at is the [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) method (and above that is a detailed description for eval).

Depending on what you are going for this might be a bad idea though. Have a look at the `local` and `global` parameters to restrict the environment.